# Adding repository unit tests

Tags: jhipster

To test the correction of extended repository methods, I created some unit tests. When I run those unit tests in Idea, all have passed. When I run the project build command with Gradle, all test cases fail with the following error message

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:76
```

I found the OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java is in the Gradle library path. The following is my unit test class structure:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class FooExtRepositoryTests {
  ...
    @Autowired
    private FooExtRepository fooRepository;
 ...
}
```

The error message indicates some sort of test configuration is missing. How to resolve this issue?